# Can I leave Switzerland while awaiting work and residence permit?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, switzerland

I  have Type D Visa stamped on my passport which is valid from 15-09-19 to 14-12-19 with multiple entries. I am moving to Geneva for work, possibly for 3 years. I have recently applied (on 2-10-19) for a student permit here which takes at least a month for processing. However, for some personal reasons I wish to travel twice within 45 days after I move during which I might not have obtained my permit. I wished to know if I could travel to (1) Schengen countries, and, (2) back home to India before my permit come (from 5-11 to 10-11)?

More specifically, does my type D visa which is valid for 3 months for multiple entries let me re-enter the country? Or do I need to apply for a fresh re-entry visa after I reach Geneva?

Also, since there is no passport control between Schengen countries, what stops me from leaving Switzerland and going into other Schengen countries like France, Spain and Germany?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually spoke to the information desk at OCPM at Geneva. The answer to both the questions is yes. Since the visa was stamped as a multi-entry visa I can indeed go to India (or any other country) and come back without an issue. And the same is true is for Schengen countries.

Since it didn't concern me I didn't ask what happens when the visa is stamped as single entry. But in that case, I am sure one can't go to any country outside Schengen area, but I am not sure whether or not you can visit other Schengen countries.